# Unable to delete file due to document awaiting archival

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, trigger, community, developer

When I click delete on a file details page to delete the files, it's giving me a popup message:

```
"This document is awaiting archival and cannot be deleted at this time. please try again later".
```

Why am I getting this message? And also what is the process to delete files?

Comment: Reading this would help https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.collab_files_deleting.htm&type=5. 
If it doesn't help show screenshot of the error. You also mentioned apex in your tag, we need to know what triggers you have on ContentVersion etc

Comment: Same issue. Any fix? For us it was after we enabled an archival solution in the org.